# <uses-sdk> tag appears after <application> tag

Tags: android, android-manifest

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this:

```
<manifest ...>
    <application ...>
        ...
    </application>
    <uses-sdk ... />
</manifest>
```

which was fine in earlier versions of Eclipse but since I upgraded I get this warning:

```
<uses-sdk> tag appears after <application> tag
```

What's best practice here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The warning is explained by lint. It's nothing serious, but rather a "better safe than sorry" policy.

Quoting lint:

```
<uses-sdk> tag appears after <application> tag

Issue: Checks for manifest problems like <uses-sdk> after the <application> tag
Id: ManifestOrder
```

> The  tag should appear after the elements which declare
>   which version you need, which features you need, which libraries you
>   need, and so on. In the past there have been subtle bugs (such as
>   themes not getting applied correctly) when the  tag
>   appears before some of these other elements, so it's best to order
>   your manifest in the logical dependency order.